# What are the file formats for different mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, mobile

I am trying to learn more about mobile application development. iOS applications are contained in a 'ipa' file.

What are the file formats for android, BlackBerry and Windows Phone Mobile.

Answer (score 7):

We're talking about application distribution format, right?

- Windows Phone 7: XAP. It's a renamed ZIP.
- Android: APK. It's a renamed ZIP.
- Windows Mobile: CAB. Also a compressed format, similar but not identical to ZIP. Many popular archivers can open those.
- Blackberry: ALX for sideloading, JAD and COD for over-the-air installation. JAD is a text file, COD is binary but no idea what's in it.
- Samsung bada: ZIP. As simple as that.

Note that Windows Phone 7 and Windows Mobile (6.x and below) have quite different app distribution models. WinMo exposes its filesystem, so a specific app distibution format is not, technically, necessary - you can copy an EXE to Program Files and run it all you want. Some old school apps expect you to do just that. CABs are more convenient, though - they install by single click.

WinPhone7 only supports installing from MS Marketplace. XAP is the format the compiler emits and that you submit to the Marketplace.

All those are packaging formats. Those files typically contain the executable, libraries (if any), resources, assets, and a manifest that describes the app. If you're wondering about the format of the executable - that's a whole another question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the App files are actually zip files with different endings. You can open these by renaming them to .zip. Androids ending is .apk. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) renaming and opening these app files on the Mac may fail in some cases. Better use a Windows or Linux machine for that.